# Unreal Engine - Separate visible mesh from physical body instance

Tags: c++, networking, unreal-engine4, physics-engine

I have an `USkeletalMeshComponent`. I have a need to move visible mesh separately from its physical body instance, i.e. instantly move physical body to a new location and smoothly move visible mesh to that location over time. I want to do this for custom network synchronization of actors between machines.

Answer (score 0):

The CharacterMovementComponent implements Client Side prediction and Interpolation of the Mesh to smooth corrections in Location updates on Remote machines.

Reviewing it in the Source Code may help you.